# Sequelize createdAt and updatedAt

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express, sequelize.js

I am using node, express, mssql and seqelize orm, but when I am fired a query it gives error column cratedAt not declared at save the query

Comment: it got resolved if we create column createdAt and updatedAt and also declare it in Model, But I don't want to use this  two column so how can I suppress it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try disabling timestamps from your model:

```
sequelize.define('modelName', {
// props
},{
    timestamps: false
})
```